# Install new rails 7.0 app with importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vite, importmap-rails

I have created a new rails 7.0 app.
In my gemfile I have

`gem 'importmap-rails' gem 'vite_rails'`

In my `config/importmap.rb`
I have the following

```
pin '@hotwired/turbo-rails', to: 'turbo.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus', to: 'stimulus.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus-loading', to: 'stimulus-loading.js', preload: true
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/controllers', under: 'controllers'
pin "bootstrap", to: "bootstrap.min.js", preload: true
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "popper.js", preload: true
```

In the `application.js` I have the following

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import "controllers";
import "popper";
import "bootstrap";
```

When I try to load the page I get an error
`Failed to resolve import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"`
The rest of the pins are failing as well.

Comment: Did you have any errors when running `rails new new_app`?

Comment: What version of yarn do you have?  Rails only works properly with 1.x.x.

Comment: either use `importmap-rails` or `vite_rails` there is little sense in using both.